# read a file with both text and binary information in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, io

I need to read binary PGM image files. Its format:

```
P5
# comments
nrows ncolumns
max-value
binary values start at this line. (totally nrows*ncolumns bytes/unsigned char)
```

I know how to do it in C or C++ using FILE handler by reading several lines first and read the binary block. But don't know how to do it in .Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking into [`Stream.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx) method. [Here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html) is how you'd read a binary file in C#. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/Managed_PGM.aspx) article discusses upon reading a PGM file.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [System.IO.Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) (and its inheriting classes, such as [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx)) and the various reader classes.

Depending on the type of stream, you can set the position.

```
stream.Position = {index of byte};
```

You could read the first section, determine at which byte the binary part starts, and read the stream from there.